# What is the sequence of taking out moss with a moss killer?

Tags: moss

I have a bit of moss growing in an area towards the back of the lawn with a 40-45° incline. I want to clean and mulch the area, so I am thinking of getting rid of the moss first.
[image]
[image]
I have a bunch of steps (that I am aware of) to take:

- Rake out the moss
- Apply the moss killer solution (like MossOut)
- Apply Lime to prevent moss from coming back
- Cover with mulch

My question is on the sequence of the first two steps. Should I rake out the moss first, spray the solution, or apply the solution, wait for the moss to die, and then rake it out?

Also, are there other things I should be doing to keep the moss at bay?